# How to monitor python script using monit

Tags: monit

I want to monitor my python script. I am trying to run the python script from monit but I am getting the error file as :

> error: 'scraper' process is not running
>    info: 'scraper' trying to restart
>    info     : 'scraper' start: '/bin/scraper start'
>    error    : 'scraper' failed to start (exit status -1) -- no output

My monit configuration file is :

```
check process scraper with pidfile /var/run/scraper.pid
start = "/bin/scraper start"
stop = "/bin/scraper stop"
```

And my scraper file is :

```
#!/bin/bash

PIDFILE=/var/run/scraper.pid

case $1 in
   start)
       source /home
       # Launch your program as a detached process
       python3 /home/user/Desktop/weather.py 2>/dev/null &
       # Get its PID and store it
       echo $! > ${PIDFILE}
   ;;
   stop)
      kill `cat ${PIDFILE}`
      # Now that it's killed, don't forget to remove the PID file
      rm ${PIDFILE}
   ;;
   *)
      echo "usage: scraper {start|stop}" ;;
esac
exit 0
```

No idea what is happening here. If anyone can help me it wil great help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sourcing /home is probably wrong.
If weather.py accesses your screen, pass in $DISPLAY so it knows where to go.

Comment: I will try on monday.. Thanks !

Comment: I am getting an error source argument required

Comment: What was the idea behind sourcing /home?  It sounds like you just removed "/home", leaving the "source" without an argument...

Comment: Actually i copied this script from stackoverflow.

Comment: Beware of blind copying...